# Angular swiper is not working Nothing is displayed

Tags: javascript, angular, swiper.js

I have such a file with markup
**HTML**

```
    <div class="reviews__inner">
      <swiper [pagination]="{ type: 'fraction'}" [navigation]="true" class="mySwiper">
        <div class="slider__one">
          <div class="wrapper__one">
            <ng-template swiperSlide>
              <div *ngFor="let slide of slides" class="slide__one">
                <div class="slide__wrap">
                  <img src="{{ slide.image }}" alt="stars" class="stars">
                  <div class="slide__title_size_s">{{ slide.title }}</div>
                  <div class="slide__subtitle_size_s">{{ slide.subtitle }}</div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </ng-template>
          </div>
        </div>
      </swiper>
    </div>
```

**.TS**

```
...
SwiperCore.use([Navigation, Pagination]);
...
```

I connected the swiper module and nothing is displayed when the page loads, and there are no errors in the console. I did everything according to the official documentation

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply ngFor on ng-template with swiperSlide directive. Currently you are creating only one slide. Also you cannot use wrapper divs like this in swiper. Follow the code below

```
<div class="reviews__inner">
    <swiper [pagination]="{ type: 'fraction'}" [navigation]="true" class="mySwiper">
        <ng-template swiperSlide *ngFor="let slide of slides">
            <div class="slide__one">
                <div class="slide__wrap">
                    <img src="{{ slide.image }}" alt="stars" class="stars">
                    <div class="slide__title_size_s">{{ slide.title }}</div>
                    <div class="slide__subtitle_size_s">{{ slide.subtitle }}</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ng-template>
    </swiper>
</div>
```

Comment: I used your fragment still nothing is displayed, only pagination 1/1

Comment: swiperSlide directive should be immediate child of swiper. See updated answer